# CSS transform-origin having no effect when using translateZ

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am using translateZ to move an element away into the distance. I would like to have the element remain aligned with the top of it's parent (ie. to shrink upwards and inwards from the sides), so am trying to set transform-origin accordingly.

```
.parent {
    perspective: 10000px;
}
.child {
    transform: translateZ(-200px);
    transform-origin: center top;
}
```

Any value I set for transform-origin however has no effect and the child element simply shrinks in from all edges proportionately as if transform-origin were using its default `50% 50%` value.

What am I doing wrong? Have tested this in Chrome and Firefox so far.

**EDIT**

Example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wz7jezlEW3fWG7GQZiac?p=preview).

Comment: Have you tried setting a thrid value for transform origin?

Comment: Up to now, I had not, but tried there (eg. added `center top 250px` in Firefox) and it had no visible effect.

Comment: Oh wait, i might have misunderstood you. Your desired result is to make the div "smaller" (by moving it to the back) but still aligned to the top border of parent?

Comment: Got it. I guess I could perhaps use scale() instead of translate

Comment: You could use `transformY`, provided you can live with setting "hardcoded" values.

Comment: Well, that's true too actually. It would work in my particular use case, though just using scale() alone proved simpler. Still puzzled about the original issue though!

Comment: If you think about `transform-origin` you will see why you're getting this issue. The first 2 values are regarding transforming on the x and y axis. You are doing neither. You're transforming on z, but the end result is limited to a 2-dimensional medium, so it is a simulation. An alternate way to think about it, if you have `transform-origin: center top;` what role would `center` play in `translateY`? The answer of course is *none*.

Comment: I was about to debate that there and then realised you are right - I was working from the misguided notion that transform-origin has relevance to the position of the view. What I should be using instead is `perspective-origin` and on the parent rather than child. Answer added below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @JonP, `transform-origin` is the wrong property to achieve the desired effect. Instead, I need to use `perspective-origin` on the parent element:

```
.parent {
    perspective: 10000px;
    perspective-origin: top;
}
.child {
    transform: translateZ(-200px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working example would probably help a lot, so we can see the same thing as you. But according to MDN, there's a 3rd property in the `transform-origin` which sets the origin  of the transform https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: Added example of what I am seeing now.